# How do I convert type int32 to int as it's not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I currently have a pandas DataFrame that contains information in this format:

```
      date  new builds  new houses  new homes  help to buy  
0   2014-06-08       5          29         79           11   
1   2014-06-15       5          30         79           11   
2   2014-06-22       6          31         82           12   
3   2014-06-29       5          31         82           12   
4   2014-07-06       5          33         86           12   
5   2014-07-13       5          33         88           13   
6   2014-07-20       5          33         87           12   
7   2014-07-27       5          33         86           13   
8   2014-08-03       5          32         86           13   
9   2014-08-10       6          31         83           12   
10  2014-08-17       5          30         86           11
```

I'm trying to parse this information through into Google Sheets via the gspread package and using `sheet.update_cell` function but I keep getting the error

> Object of type int32 is not JSON serializable

and the only reference of that data type I can find is the values in the Dataframe.

I've tried `df['new builds'].astype(int)` but this simply retains the data in that column as type `int32` and I've also tried converting it into a string first and then type `int` with `df['new builds'].astype(str).astype(int)` but no luck.

Just for further reference, this is the code I'm trying to use in order to push all data from the DataFrame into a sheet

```
number_of_columns = len(data.columns)
number_of_rows = data.shape[0]

for i in range(0, len(keyword_list)):
    column_loop = i + 1
    type(column_loop)
    for x in range(number_of_rows):
        row_loop = x + 1
        type(row_loop)
        sheet.update_cell(column_loop, row_loop, data.loc[x,keyword_list[i]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `int(data.loc[x, keyword_list[i]])` instead of `data.loc[x, keyword_list[i]]`

---

`np.int32` is not JSON serializable but python `int` is, what you have to do is just converting `np.int32` to python `int`.